# Accept Xcode 7.3 license

Tags: macos, xcode, gcc

I want to install a C/C++ compiler for Matlab R2015b.
I am running OSX El Capitan 10.11.3. 
I installed the newest version of Xcode (Xcode Version 7.3 beta 3).

According to MathWorks, Xcode 7.x should be compatible with Matlab R2015b.
http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2015b/index.html?sec=maci64
I also followed the additional steps to add support for Xcode 7.0 in MATLAB R2015b (this is the most recent post by MathWorks regarding using any Xcode 7.x)
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/246507-why-can-t-mex-find-a-supported-compiler-in-matlab-r2015b-after-i-upgraded-to-xcode-7-0#answer_194526

When I run "mex -setup" in Matlab I get the following error message:

```
Warning: Xcode is installed, but its license has not been accepted. Run Xcode
and accept its license agreement.
```

I have already tried the following in my terminal:
sudo xcodebuild -license

It loads the license and I am able to scroll through and type "agree".
Still, Matlab gives me the same error.

Comment: Have you tried to run Xcode and agree the license there?

Comment: Have you tried `xcode-select -reset` to make sure that the xcodebuild in the path is the one matlab is calling? I just had this mess up homebrew where I deleted a debug version of Xcode, but some of the tools were "missing"

Comment: I have tried but the license does not show up when you open the application.
@bmike - I just tried the reset but still no luck. Note that Matlab recognizes that Xcode is installed, but it cannot find that I agreed to the license.

Comment: I wonder if it's some odd thing in the user environment. If you log out or reboot, does gcc also complain that the license is bad? `$ gcc --version` should put out text like... 
`Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)`

Comment: No complaints that the license is bad. Only have issues when trying to do     "mex -setup" in Matlab.
Here is the terminal output for gcc --version

Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.21)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

Comment: Downgraded to the latest stable release of Xcode, 7.2.1.
Initially froze when verifying but was able to remedy this by bypassing the OSX gatekeeper with the command xattr -d com.apple.quarantine Xcode.app in the Applications directory.
Now it works! Thanks everyone for your suggestions.